# How to initialize a subscriber only when a 'if' condition meets?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I want to initialize a subscriber only when

```
if(i>0){              // 'i' is received as node argument
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/image_rect_color/compressed", 1, imageCallback);
  }
```

Problem I am facing is: main thread comes into if-scope but couldn't initialize the subscriber.
I guess problem is introduction of new scope.

BTW:This code is in main().

How can this problem be solved?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327788/how-to-initialize-a-subscriber-only-when-a-%27if%27-condition-meets?/) by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-07-06

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
ros::Subscriber sub;

if(i>0){              // 'i' is received as node argument
sub = nh.subscribe("/image_rect_color/compressed", 1, imageCallback);
}
```

This worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) with karma: 62 on 2019-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1